# meaning of "criticize"

Tags: meaning

[According to the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/criticize), "criticize" has two meanings

> to express disapproval of someone or something

> to give an opinion or judgment about a book, movie, etc

Consider this

> The government just published a new policy on housing prices. He's writing an article to **criticize** it.

Which meaning of "criticize" should I go with? I guess it is the former as it's a policy rather than literature or art.

Is my understanding correct?

---

The guy writing the article is trying to make a comment to the policy, such as the housing prices increasing due to the policy.

To convey the idea without causing ambiguity, which word could be substituted for "criticize"?

Comment: If it is an article, it should be a reasoned and balanced argument, and if so I would say it is the second. If it is a one-sided rant, then the first.

Comment: Criticism of *books, movies,* etc. is ***literary*** criticism. Nobody engages in [literary critique](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293805/literary-critique) of political policy documents - all we care about there is whether we agree with the ***ideology***, not the "artistry". But if that meaning *was* intended in some context where it wouldn't be the default interpretation, the best way to indicate that is to just switch the verb from ***criticize*** to ***critique***.

Comment: Perhaps all criticism of policy is ideological. I prefer to think that at least some is based on an assessment of effectiveness.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably combine the two into:

> to express disapproval or judgment about a book, movie, etc.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  It just gives a third (and in my opinion less useful) definition of "criticise".  Your answer should try to explain 1) is the OP's understanding of criticise correct (why or why not) and 2) How to rephrase to avoid ambiguity (if any exists, or else why no ambiguity exists.)